# Creating a top-down spaceship

Tags: 2d

I'm creating a top-down 2D space game in LIBGDX for android.

When spaceship is going forward it will look like this:

[image]

when it goes upward I want to change it's direction with a nice animation so it seems like a real spaceship. A between frame would be like this:

[image]

I have rendered the spaceship in different Z axis degrees from ship0 to ship90. Calculating rotation on XY plane wouldn't be so hard, but I don't know how to calculate the rotation on Z axis so I can choose the right sprite to use.

Answer (score 1):

When you starts going upwards you can start counting X from 0 to 90. For example you can increase X by 1 every 16 ms (for example). Then you can use X to use appropriate shipX frame.

When you stop going upward then decrease X from current value to 0 (for example 2 by every 16 ms). Then the ship should back to its prime position softly.